# How to use sed to pick up a specific paragraph and get rid of repeated ones

Tags: awk, sed, paragraphs

I want to pick up the lines begin with '---------read-------' and end with 'finish.' from a log file showing below, at the meantime, get rid of the repeated paragraphs (keep only the last match of the same paragraphs)

```
-------------read-----------  

File reading...  
1 failed  
finish.

[some unrelated messages]

-------------read-----------  
File reading...  
2 failed  
finish.

[some unrelated messages]

-------------read-----------  
File reading...  
1 failed   
finish.  
[some unrelated messages]
```

In the log file, the paragraph has fixed begin line and end line, but not fixed middle lines, so I am using
`sed -n -e "/-------------read-----------/,/finish./ p" $input_file_name`
to pick up the paragraph, but cannot remove the repeate ones (some paragraph may duplicate)

I've tried using `sed -n "0,/----read---/,/finish/ p"` or `sed -n "/----read------/,/finish/,{p;q;}"`, but they are not working.

he ideal output would be:

```
-------------read-----------  
File reading...  
2 failed  
finish.  
-------------read-----------  
File reading...  
1 failed   
finish.
```

How can I do that? I'd really appreciate it if someone could help!

Comment: If the structure of the log file is exactly as shown (the only interesting line is with word `failed`), you can use `sed -n -e "/-------------read-----------/,/finish./ p" $input_file_name | grep 'failed' | sort -u | awk '{printf "-------------read-----------\nFile reading...\n%s\nfinish.\n", $0}'` to get desired output.

Comment: `sed` can do the selection but can't eliminate the duplicates.  `awk` could do the selection and duplicate elimination; it could be used for just the duplicate elimination after preprocessing with `sed`.  You pays your money and takes your pick.  Am I right in assuming that the `1` and `2` in the example data are really longer file names in your read data?

Comment: Hi Andrey, Thank you for prompt reply! I get what your idea of doing this, but unfortunately in my real log file, it is more complicated than the example, sorry that I didn't describe it clearly. In my log file, the target paragraph has a fixed start line and end line, but middle lines are unexpected. But the paragraphs, they may duplicate in the log, that's why I want to get rid of them.

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. This problem is not that so therefore sed would be the wrong tool to try to use. Awk is the right tool for this job.

Comment: I'm not seeing the evidence of repeats. Is there a filename that you've stripped from your sample input data?  Or is a "repeat" designated only by the number of failures shown?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"") }
!NF { next }
/-------------read-----------/ { inBlock=1; block="" }
inBlock { block = block $0 RS }
/finish/ {
    if (NR==FNR) {
        lastSeen[block] = FNR
    }
    else {
        if (FNR==lastSeen[block]) {
            printf "%s", block
        }
    }
    inBlock=0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
-------------read-----------
File reading...
2 failed
finish.
-------------read-----------
File reading...
1 failed
finish.
```

Answer (score 0):

using a similar logic

```
$ awk '/-+read-+/{k=$0; next} 
            k&&NF{sub(/ *$/,""); k=k RS $0}
         /finish/{if(NR==FNR) a[k]++;
                  else if(!--a[k]) print k; 
                  k=""}' log{,}
-------------read-----------
File reading...
2 failed
finish.
-------------read-----------
File reading...
1 failed
finish.
```

keeping the last matching record creates the additional complexity.

Comment: redundant ranges in your first regex. `-+` is the same as `[-]+`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where we're supposed to look for the repeats that we don't want to repeat (your sample input doesn't appear to have filenames for example), but you can strip the unnecessary data with a simple toggle:

```
$ awk '/^-+read-+/ {show=1} show; $1=="finish." {show=0}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/-+read/,/finish\./H;$!d;x;:a;s/(\n-+read.*finish\.)(.*\1)/\2/;ta;s/.//' file
```

This stores the filtered lines in the hold space then uses pattern matching and backreferences to remove the repeated paragraphs. It is however a fragile solution as it demands that the repeated paragraphs are exact copies (unlike the example given).